# Number Theory Problem in SEAMO sample paper

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

"It is known that there is only one pair of positive integers $\text{a}$ and $\text{b}$ such that $a \le b$ and $a^2+b^2+3ab=719$. Find the value of a + b".
What I have tried(but didn't seem to work)
$$
a^2+b^2+3ab=719\\
(a+b)^2+ab=719\\
ab = 719-(a+b)^2\\
\text{The quadratic polynomial p(x) with roots a and b is}\\
p(x) = x^2-(a+b)x + ab\\
=x^2-(a+b)x+(719-(a+b)^2)\\
\text{Since p(x) has integer roots, discriminant must be a perfect square(say } k^2)\text{and let (a+b)=n}\\
5n^2-2876=k^2\\
(\root\of{5}n+k)(\root\of{5}n-k) = 2876
$$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There are infinitely many solution to the Diophantine equation $5n^2-k^2=2876$ but only one give you back positive integers $a\leq b$.  Instead, it is probably faster and easier to just search the possible $a$ with a simple bound.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $5a^2<719<5b^2$, so $a<12<b$. Put $a=12-x$ and $b=12+y$. If $y\leq x$, then
\begin{align}
(12-x)^2+(12+x)^2+3(12-x)(12+x)\geq719,
\end{align}
which simplifies to $x^2\leq 1$. The only possibility is $x=y=1$, corresponding to the solution $a=11$ and $b=13$.

For a complete treatment, consider $y>x$. Then
\begin{align}
24<12-x+12+y=a+b<\sqrt{719}.
\end{align}
This leaves two possibilities $a+b=25$ and $a+b=26$. In either case $a-b=\sqrt{719-5ab}$ is not an integer, impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(a,b)=a^2+b^2+3ab$. We cannot have $a=b$, because $719$ is a prime number. I tried
$b=a+1$ and $b=a+2$. Then $f(a,a+1)=5a^2 + 5a + 1=719$ is not possible, but
$$
f(a,a+2)=5a^2+10a+4\equiv 5(a-11)(a+13) \bmod 719.
$$
And this works! So $(a,b)=(a,a+2)=(11,13)$ is a solution.
Then $a+b=24$.